# I need to invoke a method in WCF before my operation contracts gets called

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to validate the request in all the operation contracts. The request base will have user authentication token which needs to be validated every time.

I need to invoke a method in WCF (basically to validate this request) before all my operation contracts are gets called. Otherwise I have to write the code to validate the request in all the operation contract methods.

Is there any option in WCF for this?

Comment: You can call custom code at many points in the WCF pipeline by using "behaviors". That's what you're searching for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms730137%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF offers several extensibility points. You could check [`IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to inspect an incoming message before it is dispatched to the operation.